# 301 Redirects - Advanced?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo, url-rewriting

I am in a situation where there are TWO version sof each page on my site - which runs into thousands....now this is causing all sorts of problems with Google, I am dropping down the search results due to duplicate content.  This was created as a result of enabling "SEO Friendly URLs" on my site.

Is there a way that I can rewrite ALL pages taht start with say brands.php to their SEO friendly version? e.g. /products.php?product=Oil-Pump-Star to /prducts/oil-pump-star/....without having to go through each URL manually...

Apologies if this is confusing - I find it hard to put the exact situation into written words!

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: it would be good if you can post your .htaccess so that we don't introduce any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like you are using a Joomla CMS. you could use rel="canonical" to get away with this, but this will have to be done manually unfortunately. Google still suggests using a 301 redirect, and recommends a rel="canonical" only where 301 is not possible.

I will let you decide whats best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an example without knowing the type of URLs your system is setup for.  However, based on the example you gave, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+).php?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$                   $1/$3 [NC]
```

I have not tested it, so it may need some tweaking.  You'll need to adjust your rules accordingly to work with the URLs you are trying to restructure.